# Passing a tmemorystream as a var

Tags: delphi, pointers, procedure, var

When I try to pass tmemorystream as a var or pointer to a procedure it comes back corrupted.  What is the proper way to do this?

For example:

```
function tform1.downloadmemupdate(url, desc: string; var data: tmemorystream; var msg: string): boolean;
begin
  filelabel.Caption:=desc;
  downloadmemthread:=tdownloadmemthread.create(url);
  dlcancelbtn.Enabled:=true;
  downloadmemthread.dlstart;
  waitforsingleobject(downloadmemthread.Handle, INFINITE);

  downloadmemthread.data.SaveToStream(data); //corrupted
  downloadmemthread.data.SaveToFile('data.zip');  //works

  dlcancelbtn.Enabled:=false;
  result:=not (downloadmemthread.canceled and downloadmemthread.success);
  dlcanceled:=downloadmemthread.canceled;
  msg:=downloadmemthread.msg;
  downloadthread.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't create `data` within this method. As it is a var (byref) parameter, I would expect it to be created within  `tform1.downloadmemupdate`, i.e.:

```
data := TMemoryStream.Create;
```

Note that if you create an object like this, you will need to free it somewhere else, probably in the calling code.

e.g.

```
   Data := nil;
   try
     downloadmemupdate(url, desc, data, msg);
     // do something with data
   finally
     Data.Free;
   end;
```

An alternative (and the idiomatic method in Delphi) is to pass objects by value (without the var). and leave it to the calling code to create and destroy them. This is mainly because Delphi doesn't have garbage collection, so it forces the person writing the calling code to think about "ownership".

This would be

```
function tform1.downloadmemupdate(url, desc: string; data: TStream; var msg: string): boolean;
begin
  filelabel.Caption:=desc;
  downloadmemthread:=tdownloadmemthread.create(url);
  try
    ...
    downloadmemthread.data.SaveToStream(data); //corrupted
    downloadmemthread.data.SaveToFile('data.zip');  //works    
  finally
    downloadmemthread.Free;
  end;

end;
```

calling code:

```
   Data := TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
     downloadmemupdate(url, desc, data, msg);
     // do something with data
   finally
     Data.Free;
   end;
```